# How to append unique spans to a table in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quick question, because my brain refuses to think this evening.

### HTML

```
<table>
</table>

<span>2010</span>
<span>2009</span>
<span>2009</span>
<span>2009</span>
<span>2008</span>
<span>2008</span>
<span>2007</span>
```

### jQuery

```
$('span').each(function() {
        $("table").append("<tr><td>"+$(span).text()+"</span>)</td></tr>";
});
```

### Desired Output

```
<table>
<tr><td>2010</td></tr>
<tr><td>2009</td></tr>
<tr><td>2008</td></tr>
<tr><td>2007</td></tr>
```

The idea is, that I want to display just a year that is not duplicated.

I hope that you understood me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do inline string replacement like that.

You need to concatenate using JavaScript's (stupidly dual purpose) `+` operator.

You also can't access the `span` like that. Use `this`, which jQuery sets as the current element being iterated. Wrap it in `$()` to use jQuery on it again.

To remove the original, just call `remove()` on `$(this)`.

```
var yearsUsed = [];
$('span').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();   

    if ($.inArray(text, yearsUsed) === -1) {
        $('table').append('<tr><td>' + text  + '</span>)</td></tr>');
        yearsUsed.push(text);
    }
    $(this).remove();
});
```

You should also pick one string delimiter and stick with it - here I chose single quotes (`'`).

Comment: lol, I just change this line "if ($.inArray(text, yearsUsed) === -1" as well

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').each(function() {
  $("table").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).text() + "</td></tr>");
  $(this).hide();
  });
```

Comment: Also correct, but a quick note on the difference between this code and alex's: $.hide only sets the element's display property to "none", while $.remove removes the element from the DOM completely. Which one you should choose depends on whether you want to do any future processing on those spans.